# Send an email verfication email to a new Firebase User in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I have my app set up to successfully login or create an account with Firebase using an email address and a password.
What I want to do now is to check if the user has verified their email, and if not send them the Verification email that Firebase allows us to write.

```
@IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in

            if let firebaseError = error {

                print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)

                return

            }

            self.presentTabBar()

        })

    }

}

@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in

            if let firebaseError = error {

                print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)

                return

            }

            self.presentTabBar()

        })

    }

}
```

Here are my "createaccount" and "login" functions.

My problem is that I don't know how to implement this functionality, and where to call those functions.

Can you show me what the function to send this email is, and what the function to check if the email is verified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send the verification mail just after creating the account:

*(Don't forget to create an additional button/action so the user may ask for the verification mail again)*

```
private var authUser : User? {
    return Auth.auth().currentUser
}

public func sendVerificationMail() {
    if self.authUser != nil && !self.authUser!.isEmailVerified {
        self.authUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
            // Notify the user that the mail has sent or couldn't because of an error.
        })
    }
    else {
        // Either the user is not available, or the user is already verified.
    }
}
```

Combining with your code:

```
@IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in

            if let firebaseError = error {
                print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            sendVerificationMail()


            self.presentTabBar()
        })
    }
}
```

To check if the user has verified:

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in
            if let firebaseError = error {
                print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if user != nil && !user!.isEmailVerified {
            // User is available, but their email is not verified.
            // Let the user know by an alert, preferably with an option to re-send the verification mail.
            }
            self.presentTabBar()
        })
    }
}
```